# CancellationToken and request cancellation via Angular

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, .net-6.0, angular15

I'm trying to cancel a request from the client side (Angular) and while the request is indeed canceled according to Chrome's network tab, the server is never made aware of such cancellation.

Here's the code on the front end, pretty simple.

```
if (this.subscription) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

this.subscription = this._queueService.queueJob().subscribe(_ => {
    console.log("Done queuing!");
});

// The queueJob function...
queueJob(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.post(`queue`, { userId: Math.random() });
}
```

And on the server side:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Object dto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{            
    var ct = HttpContext.RequestAborted;

    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
        
    return Ok(new { Message = "Queued OK!" } );
}
```

I read that to make sure `HttpContext.RequestAborted` and/or that the `cancellationToken` parameter is correctly bound, either `services.AddMvc()` or `services.AddMvcCore()` need to be added in `Program.cs`

I've tried both. And as you can see, I also tried invoking `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` two different ways.

None ever trigger.

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: How are you running this code? I know there used to be an issue with IIS/IIS Express.

Comment: Your `cancellationToken` parameter and `HttpContext.RequestAborted` value are both effectively aliases of each other, so half of your code is redundant. Also, what's with the `for` loop?

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of what you see in Chrome's DevTools. I suspect the request may be being cancelled  _after_ ASP.NET Core already returned a response.

Comment: @Dai it shows a bunch of canceled requests and the last one being in "pending".

Comment: You should use Wireshark to verify the HTTP connection was closed instead of browser devtools because (in my experience) Chrome's DevTools hide a lot of the low-level details.

Comment: @Dai It's definitely something to do with `Program/Startup.cs`. In this basic solution I can't get it to work, but I just tried doing it in our main product solution and it works fine.

Comment: How are you invoking the cancellation request part? This has to be a separate API request to do the actual cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more involved to cancel a running server request. The client would need to hold onto some sort of identifier that can be used on a separate API method dedicated to cancelling long-running in process requests.

The flow would look something like this:

1. Client side makes an API request to the server
2. Server spins up a background thread, and invokes it to run in the background; Server also returns back to the client a "task identifier" (more on this later)
3. The server should retain a mapping of [task identifiers / running tasks].
4. The client can hold onto this task identifier, and if the client wants to cancel the pending request, it can call a separate API to actually cancel the pending task
5. The server can lookup the task to cancel by its identifier, and then invoke the task instance's cancel method

### About the Task Identifier

The task identifier can be anything that is unique. A `Guid` would be perfect for this scenario.

The server should have a dictionary with the key being the task identifier, and for the value, an instance of a `Task`.

This dictionary should be available "across server requests", so something like registering a "singleton" in a dependency injection framework would be an option.
 
The server should expose an API method that takes in a task identifier, and then can lookup the task to cancel in the dictionary.

Comment: Where does `CancellationToken` fit in your solution then ?